# Why is this c++ program to reverse a word not working

Tags: c++, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

I am extremely new to c++ and wrote this program to reverse a word. What I tried was to basically loop through an array and swap first letter with the last, second with the second last etc. However the result  is some wired characters `╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠Ω ⌠7p≈╗`. I don't want a work-around since there are plenty of examples online. I just want to know why what I am doing wont work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char word[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        word[i] = word[sizeof(word - i)];
    }

    cout << word << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It is also giving me this warning `warning C6001: using uninitialized memory 'word'`. But I though I initialized the memory by doing `char word[10]`.

Comment: You array contains nothing. It is uninitialized. What are you going to reverse?!

Comment: `word[i] = word[sizeof(word)-i];`

Comment: Oh sorry, how did I not notice that

Comment: You have marked this C++, use `std::string`, to reverse a string, you just construct it with the reverse iterators of another i.e. `auto reversed_string = std::string(mystr.rbegin(), mystr.rend())`.

Comment: You change the code in your question from `char word[10];` to `char word[5] = {'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'};`. You must not do such fundamental changes because now not only does the error message no longer match the code, but also the already given answers no longer match the question (and have to be updated).

Comment: @t.niese I changed it back

Comment: @hippozhipos Your initial change already resulted in some answers to be updated, having answers to the old question, and answers to the new one. So neither the first nor the current version for the questions is really matching right now. That's why you shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is what `sizeof(word - i)` actually does.

Short answer: it returns pointer size (4 or 8).

More detailed answer:

- `word` has type `char[10]` and size `10`
- when you do `word + 1`, the compiler will decay array to pointer to char to be able do this operation. So result type is `char *`
- now `sizeof(char *)` is 4 or 8 depending on what platform you build it (32 or 64 bits)
- so `word[sizeof(word - i)]` always refers to the same cell

There is also a second problem. In `C`, strings of text must be null terminated to indicate the size of it. Your  `word` contains `apple` without zero character at the end, so garbage is printed after `apple` (it may even crash program).

Also, your code is more C like, in C++ this can be done like this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::string word{"apple"};
    std::string reversed{word.rbegin(), word.rend()};
    std::cout << word << '\n';
    std::cout << reversed<< '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three problems.

The first one is that the array is not initialized and has an indeterminate value.

```
char word[10];
```

The second one is that this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

in any case will not reverse the array.

Even after you updated the array like

```
char word[5] = {'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'};
```

nevertheless the loop does not make sense.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

And this expression

```
sizeof(word - i)
```

is incorrect. This expression `word - i` has the type `char *` due to the pointer arithmetic. At least you mean

```
sizeof(word ) - i
```

Instead you could write something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <cstring>

//...

char word[] = "Hello World!";

for ( size_t i = 0, n = std::strlen( word ); i < n / 2; i++ )
{
    std::swap( word[i], word[n - i - 1] );
}

std::cout << word << std::endl;
```

Or you could write a separate function. Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <cstring>

char * reverse( char *s )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0, n = std::strlen( s ); i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        std::swap( s[i], s[n - i - 1] );
    }

    return s;
}

int main() 
{
    char word[] = "Hello World!";
    
    std::cout << word << '\n';
    std::cout << reverse( word ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World!
!dlroW olleH
```

Comment: 3rd problem: `sizeof(word - i)`

Answer (score 0):

In your case `word` is **declared** but not **initialized**. That warning means word array can contain un-initialized values.

```
   char word[10];
```

To see sensible characters rather than garbage (uninitialized) value, either inputs value to `word` or initialize it in code.

Why this behaviour? the stack contains trash until the program places specific values into variables defined on the stack.

Comment: arrays cannot be empty. Also the thing about "garbage" is a bit confusing. Trying to use an uninitialized value is undefined behavior. Thats all. "garbage" or "random" values is only a symptom of what the compiler does if you let it compile invalid code

Comment: Thank you. Updated the answer and removed the empty and garbage wordings.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(word - 1)` will be 4, or 8. Since it's a pointer.
What you need is `strlen(word)`.

Also, `word` is not initialized, do something like `char word[10] = "blabla"`.

Note, that for the edit you did, where:

```
    char word[5] = {'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'};
```

`strlen` will not work, since you need a character to be null, or `0`, to know where the string ends.

Also, it seems you're writing in C++, for such things you have `std::string`, you don't need a char array. and than you can call `word.length()` for the length, and it can dynamically set the size it needs for the string and grow.

Answer (score 0):

C/C++ doesn't have an auto initialization for declared variable. You must fill in each of the array with a value before referencing because C/C++ is using pointers.